# is there a way to free up space after Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation, uninstallation

I have just installed VS2010 SP1 and it takes a huge amount of space. What I would like to know is if it's possible to remove the SP1 uninstall files, and thus free up some space.

For example after installing Windows 7 SP1, there is a command (`dism /online /cleanup-image /spsuperseded`) to clean up all the space, if you don't want to uninstall SP1 afterwards. Is there a similar command for VS2010 SP1?

Answer (score 0):

One really nice tip to get free space is removing  Hiberfil.sys. This file is only used to allow you to hibernate your machine. But, i think as a developer you can remove thius file. Since that you dont use to much this feature.

http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-delete-hibernation-file-hiberfil-sys/

Comment: it's indeed a space hog but it has absolutely nothing to do with visual studio

Comment: Aggree, i just provide another fair way to get a lot of space in your windows 7 machine.